# Est-ce que c'est toujours "à faire" ou " à + verbe" après "avoir + nom" ou "être + adjectif” ?

Tags: grammaire

Les expressions comme "avoir intention" ou "être destiné" sont toujours suivies par "à".

Est-ce que "avoir + nom + à " ou "être + adjectif + à ” sont des structures figées ?

Comment: Absolument pas, même si **de** est fréquent avec avoir il faut apprendre l'expression et la préposition qui va avec. On trouve facilement des listes.

Comment: *J'avais l'intention **de** répondre*.

Comment: _avoir intention à_ ne se dit pas. C'est _avoir l'intention de_.

Answer (score 1):

### Non

*Avoir intention à* n'existe pas. Google ngrams ne recense même pas une seule occurence de cette expression.

Pour *être destiné*, le même outil nous indique que ces deux mots sont suivis de "à" environ les deux tiers du temps.

En fait, pour *être destiné*, on comprend assez intuitivement que l'expression seule n'apporte pas vraiment d'information, et qu'on va donc dans l'écrasante majorité des cas vouloir préciser la nature de cette destinée. Ne pas le préciser ce n'est pas une erreur grammaticale, c'est simplement omettre l'information.

De manière générale, en français il vaut mieux voir la préposition comme associée à ce qui suit, pas à ce qui la précède:

> Avoir peur du loup.

> Avoir peur à cause du loup.